Finding a function $\hat{\mu}:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ for a data set $X_i:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ that minimizes the sum of squared distances to that function
Not long ago I requested an algorithm that can find the word minimizing the sum of squared Hamming distance of all words in a data set. The answer to this question is that the minimization problem is NP-hard, though there are some approximation algorithms one could use. This question expands on the previous question by considering a continuous analogue of the Hamming distance. The original problem was an optimization problem over a discrete but potentially large set. Sometimes, though, a continuous version of the minimization problem is easier, so I want to explore it.
Let $f_1:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ and $f_2:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ be two Lebesgue-integrable functions; we'll even assume they're continuous almost everywhere. The continuous version of the Hamming distance will then be $d(f_1, f_2)=\int_0^1 \left|f_1(t)-f_2(t)\right|dt$; this is the $L_1$-norm of the distance between the two functions, and it's easy to see that any $L_p$ norm for $p>1$ is simply the $L_1$ norm raised to the power of $1/p$. Given a data set $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ of such functions, the Fréchet mean function is a function $\hat{\mu}:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ that minimizes:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}d^2(X_i,\hat{\mu}).$$
Is finding this mean function computationally feasible? I don't believe it is, but I'm not a computer scientist (I'm a mathematician), so I do not trust my judgement completely. I think proving this is NP-hard could be done like so: if you had an algorithm that solved this problem in polynomial time, you would have an algorithm that could solve the discrete analogue in polynomial time as well; simply translate your discrete words into functions that are continuous and constant everywhere except at jump point that are multiples of $1/m$, where $m$ is the length of the word. Since we know that the discrete problem is NP-hard, that makes the continuous analogue NP-hard as well. I do not know if this is valid inference for algorithmic computing time, though.
If I am correct, and this problem is also NP-hard, what do we gain (if anything) in terms of heuristics by viewing the problem as continuous rather than discrete? Is the heuristic of using a sample minimizer the only one we have, or do we gain others?

I don't think it's true that the $L_p$ norm is the $L_1$ norm raised to the power $1/p$.  Are you sure about that statement?

How are the functions specified in the input (in finite length)?  It takes infinitely many bits to specify a function on $[0,1]$.

@D.W. In general it's not true, but in this case it is. The integrand would be raised to the power $p$, but the integrand is only 0 or 1 at every $t$, so you're always computing $0^p$ or $1^p$ which does not depend on $p$ for $p > 1$. Second, if I assume finite discontinuities, then the function can be represented in a computer via just the points of discontinuity. That's what we will have in practice.

I understand your statement about the $L_p$ norm now, thank you for explaining.

I have a suspicion (but no proof) that the continuous version of the problem might be tractable.
Let's assume that each function $f \in X$ has the form $f(x)=c_i$ if $d_i < x < d_{i+1}$, for some $d_i$'s such that $0=d_1 < d_2< \dots < d_n=1$ (the same $d_i$'s for every $f$).  This assumption is without loss of generality, since you can always put the function into this form by letting the $d_i$'s be the points of discontinuity of the functions in $X$ together with $0,1$.
Define the vector $\mu$ by
$$\mu_i = {1 \over |X|} \sum_{f \in X} f(x)$$
for some $x \in (d_i,d_{i+1})$ (the particular $x$ doesn't matter).
Consider the function $\eta$ given by $\eta(x) = \mu_i$ if $d_i < x < d_{i+1}$.  I have a suspicion this function might be a global minimizer of your objective function.  However, it is not admissible, because its range is not $\{0,1\}$.  So we will instead define a function $\hat{\eta}$ that (intuitively) behaves much like $\eta$ for the purposes of this problem, except its range is $\{0,1\}$.
Specifically, define the function $\hat{\mu}$ so that $\hat{\mu}(x) = 1$ if $d_i < x < d_i + \mu_i (d_{i+1}-d_i)$ and $\hat{\mu}(x) = 0$ if $d_i + \mu_i (d_{i+1}-d_i) < x < d_{i+1}$.  Notice that $\int_{x=d_i}^{x=d_{i+1}} \hat{\mu}(x) \; dx = \mu_i (d_{i+1}-d_i)$.
Now I have a suspicion that this function $\hat{\mu}$ might be a global minimizer for your problem.  Or if not, it might be a good heuristic.
I have no proof, so this could be totally wrong.  I suggest trying it out for yourself to see whether it seems to be correct or not.

That does make sense. Now, on to my suspicion that it might be intractable due to relating it to the discrete problem. What's my error? (Reasoning about algorithm complexity is not something I've ever been trained to do, so I'd like to know what error I may have made.)

@cgmil, Your argument assumes that the optimal function $\hat{\mu}$ has jump points at the same locations as the functions $f \in X$.  I suspect that isn't necessarily true and it is possible to reduce the value of the objective function by choosing a function $\hat{\mu}$ that has additional jump points, such as in my answer above.  Such a function $\hat{\mu}$ won't correspond to any solution to the discrete problem (it can't be translated back to a solution to the discrete version of the problem).
